# ошибка при загрузке картинок на yii2

Tags: yii2, upload, img

Пытаюсь использовать этот виджет https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput.

Когда я нажимаю кнопку **загрузить** то получаю ошибку SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.
Но если я нажимаю **сохранить** то изображение сохраняется и в базе и в своей папке uploads
Подскажите пожалуйста что не так? Самому уже никак не получается исправить

[image]
[image]

models/Photo.php

```
...
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['img'], 'required'],
            [['file'],'file','maxSize' => '5242880' ], // 'extensions' => 'jpg'
            [['img'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }
...
```

PhotoController.php

```
...
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $imageName = rand(1000,100000);
            $model -> file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
            $model -> file -> saveAs('uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension);
            $model -> img = '@web/uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
            $model->save();
            if ($model->save()) {
                \Yii::$app -> response -> format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
                $result = [];

                return $result;
//                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
...
```

view/update.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
//use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\file\FileInput;
use kartik\form\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Url;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\modules\user\models\Photo */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="photo-form container">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

<!--    --><?//= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput(); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'file')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
        'options' => ['accept'=>'image/*'],
        'pluginOptions'=>[
            'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['/uploads']),
            'allowedFileExtensions'=>['jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
            'showUpload' => true,
            'initialPreview' => [
//                    $model-> img ? Html::img($model-> img) : null, // checks the models to display the preview
            ],
            'overwriteInitial' => false,
        ],
    ]); ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Ну как бы а где вы отдаёте ответ в JSON? Вижу только `return $this->redirect(['index']);` что явно им не является.

Comment: Также не вижу actionUploads и модели Users

Comment: @Ninazu Добавил actionUploads и модель Users

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите файл должен был таки загрузится судя по коду. Только если у модели **UploadForm** нет ошибок. Подебажте actionUpload. Чаще всего возникают проблемы из-за прав на папку для загрузки.

Подробнее о структуре ответа можно почитать тут

http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#async-send

Сейчас проверить у себя не могу. Но по идее должно заработать даже с пустым ответом

```
\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
$result = [];

return $result;
```

Вместо вот этого.

```
echo 'file is uploaded successfully';
```

Comment: есть некоторый прогресс в этой задаче. Нашел пару ошибок в коде. Отдельно вынес все формы и загрузку изображения , добавил ваш код в actionUpdate. При нажатии загрузить выходит та же ошибка. А при нажатие сохранить изображение сохраняется в папке uploads и в базе

Comment: Посмотрите куда отправляется запрос при загрузке картинки. Экшен, контроллер. Возможно вы не туда отправляете. Или результатом экшена является не json строка. Проверьте в инспекторе. Также если вы хотите получить preview то нужно отдавать с сервера их конфигурацию. об этом по ссылке в документации